# How to 'pretty up' an ugly piece of industrial design for electronics

Tags: design, hardware

Allow me to apologize in advance if this question is too far out for the UX site.

Here is a generic box for electronics:

[image: generic box]

As you can tell, this won't be winning any industrial design awards. However, it is similar to a box I have to work with, and I have to improve the perception it will give to an end user of the brand's **quality, technological capability, and modernism** (despite the ugly exterior, the capabilities within are powerful).

**About the User**: These boxes are going to be sitting on office workers' desks (or somewhere nearby). It isn't for consumers. It also isn't a box users 'interact' with at all except for a couple of LED lights that indicate that it's working.

**The constraint**: we cannot change the shell (this picture is the actual box we have to use), and we need to make each box look as good as possible with very little expenditure and very little assembly time.

Approaches we've thought of so far:

- Add a brightly colored company logo
- Add dark stickers, possibly subtly patterned, possibly over the gaps on top, to give a cleaner and more modern look.
- Spray paint the whole thing with a rubberized coating then put a decal on top of that.

I don't know what the options are - we've thought of accent labels, background labels, and rubberized coatings. **What other avenues are possible** to improve the user's experience of a box like this without changing the shell itself?

Comment: I like the question but it doesn't belong here.

Comment: UX isnt about making things pretty

Comment: @theotherone I could've chosen my words more carefully. I'm not just interested in what makes it 'pretty' but what simple types of improvements might make it seem more modern and dependable to an end user. I would argue that good design makes a user infer other opinions about a brand, such as its quality, ethos, and so on.

Comment: @theotherone, not IN THEORY, or NECESSARILY. But your statement is quite a reach, otherwise companies spending billions of dollars in design might be wrong. Always remember you're working in an EXPERIENCE for the user, and it includes aesthetical values as well. If in doubt, ask Apple ;)

Comment: @sscirrus, it would be very helpful to know what is this for and the target audience, otherwise it's really difficult to provide an answer

Comment: @Devin I've added some info on the typical user to the question.

Comment: Making things look pretty is a *part* of UX, but only a part, so yea, this maybe isn't the place. That said, I don't think we have an Industrial Design stackexchange. Not sure where to post it.

Comment: Also, it sounds like the casing is already made? If so, then you can't really fix it. You're only adding lipstick. Your comment on industrial design is spot-on, though. You need an industrial designer as part of the design and manufacturing process. As for us being able to provide feedback, we need to know what the device does.

Comment: @DA01 That's correct - this is an actual product and we have to add the best 'lipstick' we can to it. I know we could make it 10X nicer if we design a whole new thing, but this project does not give us the luxury. Under heavy budget and time constraints, what would the experts do?

Comment: @sscirrus there's really not much you can do. It is what it is and 'decorating' it will likely make the whole thing feel even cheaper and less thought out than it currently is. I think paint and stickers would just make it tacky. Maybe you could add an accouterment of some sort? Maybe a stand?

Comment: Why would it not win industrial design awards? If it's convenient to manufacture and distribute, sturdy, etc.? Aren't you instead looking for experience-driven design methods here? Something different from user experience design despite similar names.

Comment: @sscirrus it's impossible to know what's wrong with your actual box without seeing it. For instance here, there is tacky plastic, ugly, easy to fix with a paint that leaves a powdery texture. The holes, are they for air circulation or just for manufacture convenience? i.e. can you sticker them or do you need a grid over them? Grids -> a ton of materials and colours can give different feels of quality to the product. Hardly anything you can do about the edges without redesigning the mould though. Have you considered adding a plastic cover over it? Like Fugoo sport speakers do.

Comment: And of course, even if you buy / already have a stock of the plastic boxes, we can't really know what options are available without a budget and without knowing your manufacturing abilities and the scale of your product distribution. Really more of a question for professional consultants than for the Internet :-)

Comment: @SteveDL The question is really quite simple - the scale is too small for any kind of custom-manufacturing or hardware-based alterations to the box. We can do simple-ish things that require human effort - painting, spray-painting, labels, etc. The holes are not necessary and can be covered up.

Comment: Maybe you will find Hengfeng Zuo's research useful for ideating, then: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=s-zD18tR7y4C&pg=PP27&lpg=PP27#v=onepage&q&f=false

You can play on coarseness, colour, light reflection, contrasts on edges (whether using spray-painting, labels, resin coatings, sticky vynils or veneers). Look up (using H. Zuo's research and Google, also by *looking at your competition* as these perceptions are influenced by culture / product type) the properties you want on your surfaces. Then do a few prototypes and A/B test them or have them ranked by a focus group?

Comment: I really feel like shape matters just as much, though you can't change it. What you should aim to is to ensure the object's shape doesn't make users perceive it as a raw plastic part. When you buy e.g. a router for consumer markets, it often has slim, slightly curvy shapes and the controls and protuberances are hidden (hence my suggest of a custom-made casing, or maybe at least glueing-screwing a hard material on the front surfaces with longer edges to partially/totally mask protuberances on the sides). For IT pro markets, the shape follows the use: it's going to be racked and must be square.

Comment: I have absolutely ZERO professional skills in product design so won't write up an answer. Hope the mumbling above helps. I encourage you to get hold of a pro.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do more by using the technique of prototyping.

1. Get a sheet of paper and a pen and start drawing different ideas of how the box would ideally look like. Try doing different styles (colorful, small logo, different logo position, etc.). Be creative and draw as much as you can. Here you can do a quick 15-20 designs and then pick 2-3 that seems to look like the most promising.
2. Start building up a 2 or 3 tangible prototypes using plasticine or other plastic materials and then show it to your colleagues. They will give you feedback which they seem to like more and maybe how it could be improved.
3. Improve the one that is most preferred by you and your colleagues.

Have in mind the purpose that this product will have. In what context it would be used. It would be very beneficial if you try to use that product in your daily life and see how it could be made better for the context of use.

**Update:**

Well then look at the Apple products if you want your product to look modern. Right now the mode is to use minimalistic style/design. Look at their products and try to use similar design. Of course don't fully copy them, just take ideas.

P.S. The rubber coating is a good idea if your device would be held in hand often. If not there is no point of doing it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For the purposes of this project, I do not have any ability to alter the hardware. I'm mostly interested in general strategies for how designers might make a box like this feel more attractive, modern, dependable, etc. for an end user.

Comment: Follow-up - I guess part of the question is that I don't know what options exist for improving a box like this. Of course, colors/logos etc are up to my team but are there labels, stickers, coatings, add-ons etc. that can help?

Comment: @Kristiyan, I gotta admit I love your answers, always smart and to the point :)

Comment: @KristiyanLukanov I appreciate your answer and edit but neither are quite what I'm asking - we know about prototyping methods and of course to look at popular consumer-grade products for inspiration, but the question is more specific: what kinds of techniques can we use (I gave the examples of stickers/labels/decals and rubber coatings) without changing the case itself to adapt the above box to make it look/feel better?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have access to brushed steel, and wish to create a new box, made from it, with nice smooth bevels and a near-square shape with as few alterations from a cubic-box shape as possible, I am afraid your out of luck.

However, most products benefit from a pretty metallic sticker with the branding printed on top of it. Think about Intel and the stickers they use to promote themselves on the fronts of PCs everywhere. That metallic sticker always made a PC I used look nicer IMO.

If you take the sticker route, please don't over due it. Just something small and simple is enough, I'd say something no larger than 1/3 the surface area of the top of the box and no smaller than 1/8 respectively!

Best of luck!